# One Drive API - Downloading documents as PDF

Tags: onedrive

Can I download files (docx, pptx, xlsx) saved to One Drive as PDF using the One Drive API?

I am able to do this using the Google Drive API using getExportLinks and specifying the application/pdf MIME Type to obtain a download URL.

Using Google is not an option so I'm looking for alternatives.

I don't see anything similar to this in the One Drive documentation.